# positioning the image views in android

Tags: android-layout

i wish to position the different imageviews in android.I am using FrameLayout for this one.It works in Samsung S3.When i view the same page in samsung galaxy Y,the last imageview added positioned at the top and rest of the imageview doesn't appear on that page.

Answer (score 1):

when you use FrameLayout as the parent,I dont think u will be having the felxibility to position the Image views.So if you wanted to position it diffrent locations better Go with RelativeLayout as parent. 
I feel from your question,you might be using hardcored values for android:padding or android:layoutmargin. that y you are not able see the images on Galaxy Y as comp galaxy s3 galaxy y is samll resolution phone.